# Hierarchical html table, putting last td on next line

Tags: html, css, html-table, hierarchical-data, nested-table

I'm creating a simple hierarchical table with html and CSS and I'm getting into trouble with formatting the last `td` element with class `.child` to be on next line.

I want to have the nested table inside `table > tr > td.child` becase each table can be sorted and javascript sorters don't implement any grouping of rows (my problem of having nested table could be easily solved by moving the `.child > table` element into next `table > tr` however this would break the nice nesting structure)

Is there a way to put `td.child` on next row with css?

*html sample:*

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>I have</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>pie</td>
      <td class="child">
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td>I have</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>pie</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if you add the td with class child, within a new <tr> tag?

Comment: I don't want to add a sibling to tr, because of table sorters and how they compare rows. If I put a `tr` into another `tr` most browser will cut it out and put it to previous `tr` as a sibling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **could** do something [like this](http://jsbin.com/uwure5) . You'd need to be careful cross browser though (only checked on Chrome)

Comment: looks ok in FF 3.6.13, but chokes in IE

Comment: thank you, still having problems styling the table, so it would behave as a classical table :)

Comment: broken link, that's why its not good practice to just share the link, include minimal example